# Creating my first iPhone app.. Relocating block

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

So i have a block moving with the help of iPhones built-in accelerometer, and another block that randomly appears on the screen. I'm trying to use an if statement to determine if the moving block taps or touches the immobile target-block, in which if it does it'll relocate to another position on the screen randomly. Everything works BESIDES determining if the two coordinates are equal at any given point. Here's so far..

**edit:** **so I removed the xx & yy variables and replaced them with self.xVar and self.yVar which seemed to work for a bit, but was very sketchy and stopped*

**edit2:** **so it removing the xx and yy did help, but it only works for 2-3 taps, and then stops.

**edit3** **realized that having the same x OR y variable isn't right way to go about this..

```
-(void) accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{
...

    //Make the new point
    CGPoint buttonNewCenter = CGPointMake(newX,newY);
    Button.center = buttonNewCenter;


    int xx = self.xVar;
    int yy = self.yVar;

    if (newX == xx || newY == yy) {
        int randX = arc4random() % 320;
        int randY = arc4random() % 548;

        CGPoint randNewPlace = CGPointMake(randX, randY);
        Rand.center = randNewPlace;
    }

}
```

...
...

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self awakeaccelerometer];

    int randX = arc4random() % 320;
    int randY = arc4random() % 548;

    CGPoint randNewPlace = CGPointMake(randX, randY);
    Rand.center = randNewPlace;

    self.xVar = (randX+15);
    self.yVar = (randY+15);


}
```

So the opening function determines randomly where the target-block is places, whilst the other block moves freely on the screen based on the accelerometer. I'm trying to determine `if self.xVar || self.yVar == newX || newY` at any given time. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there anyway to detect when two objects meet on the screen? Without using coordinates since it won't work. Thanks

Comment: Hmm... any recommendations?

Comment: Do you need it to pass over that exact coordinate? I imagine it getting it to hit that tiny spot is pretty difficult. It will also not register "taps" or "nudges" since they will need to share a center point, unless of course your boxes are 1x1 in size. Maybe using a range of valid coordinates would show more hit results (i.e., the widths of the boxes factored into X and height into Y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you are trying to see if two points are in the same place rather than seeing if the two rectangles intersect.  Points are very small.  If what you want to do is to see whether a point is within a rectangle, you can use `CGRectContainsPoint`.  (See the discussion on apple's website [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html).)  If you want to see whether two rectangles intersect (which I think is what you are trying to do), use `CGRectIntersectsRect`.  (You may need to call CGRectMake first.)

If you really want to do the math, then check if `(self.x+self.width<new.x or new.x+new.width<self.x or self.y+self.height<new.y or new.y+new.height<self.y)`

Comment: ps.  I think you mean rectangles.  Using the word 'block' makes it sound like you are trying to do something with an anonymous function.